# How to symlink one user profile to another?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to symlink one users profile to another?

To test, I created a new user. I symlinked one user's profile creating a new directory with the same name as my new users profile.

But, when I log out, and attempt to log in it automatically logs me straight back out again. Is there anything I need to update in the registry?

The reason why I need to do this is because I want to carry over all app settings, browser history/bookmarks etc from one account to the other.